# New to C++ - & symbol infront of parameter

Tags: c++, reference

I am a c# developer learning/relearning/brushing up on c++

I'm working on database access I have the following code and im having trouble understand what the & does in this case.

```
SQLHENV     hEnv = NULL;

if (SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv) == SQL_ERROR)
    {
```

If I remove the & I get this error.

```
'SQLAllocHandle' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'SQLHENV' to 'SQLHANDLE *'
```

at first I thought it was simply passing this field in as a reference but based on the error it reads more like it is some how allowing it to convert?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the address operator `&`? The function requires a pointer to a SQLHENV.

Comment: I don't I was just trying to learn from the error why it was there in the first place.

Comment: Don't hesitate writing the steps that you've done in that order you've done. This can help to understand the question better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of your current example, the `&` operator is used to obtain the address of a variable.

From the error message, it looks like `SQLAllocHandle` expects the parameter 3 to be of type `SQLHANDLE *` (pointer to `SQLHANDLE`).

When you "removed" the `&`, you passed a `SQLHENV` to it, which could not be converted to the required type. But when you did "include" the `&`, it worked because I am guessing `SQLHANDLE` is `typedef`ed to `SQLHENV`, or a `SQLHENV*` is convertible to `SQLHANDLE*` due to inheritance or other reason.

I need to do guesswork because the signatures of `SQLAllocHandle` and the class relation of `SQLHENV` and `SQLHANDLE` is not mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 6):

When appearing as a unary operator in an expression, `&` is the address-of operator. The code you're showing passes a pointer to `hEnv` into `SQLAllocHandle()`.

You might want to pick up a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the address operator. It's taking the local hEnv and passing the address of it.  Now you have not the type but a pointer to the type you are referring.

so

```
void foo()
{
     int i = 1; 
     int * iptr = &i; 
}
```

When you skip the address operator you still have the type, not the pointer to the type.

Answer (score -4):

& does mean to pass by reference. The compiler is just telling you it can't convert from a reference to value type

EDIT: When a function accepts an ADDRESS(pointer), it is called pass by reference. I'm sorry if my answer confused some people, but in this case your function is expecting a REFERENCE to a variable, so you need to pass it the ADDRESS of that variable.

Comment: -1: In this case, it's not passing by reference, it's taking the address.

Comment: `typename&` may be a reference, but `&variable` is taking an address.

Comment: In C++, "pass by reference" means declare the parameter type as a reference. If the parameter type is a pointer, it is a pointer passed by value.

Comment: So, effectively, you are reversing the roles of what I said? I was saying that if you expect a pointer you need to pass an address, but what the OP's scenario is is expecting an address, so you have to pass it a pointer?
Effectively, both ways pass a memory location as the parameter though...

Comment: the answer might be wrong but the explanations of why actually go further than just the answer to helping understand the difference.Since I can now see the difference between address and by ref.